# Ruby gem-ы необходимые для создания панели администрирования

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Какие нужны gem-ы для того, чтобы написать admin panel, где можно делать просто редактирование, изменение базовой информации (текст и ссылки), создать альбом, добавлять/удалять фотографии в landing page?

Как я понял, есть общая база данных, куда админ через admin panel добавляет данные, а landing page берет от нее.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы посмотрите в исходный код гема rails, то увидите, что в нем практически нет ruby-кода, он объединяет множество других гемов в фреймворк. Средств данного фреймворка достаточно, чтобы написать почти какой угодно сайт.

Вы сможете использовать ActiveRecord модели для взаимодействия с базой данных, ActionPack обеспечит работу с контроллерами и представлениями, i18n позволит вам локализовать приложение, Rack - взаимодействовать с Web-серверами, ActionMailer - отправлять почту и множество других гемов входящих в состав Rails.

Единственное, что я бы посоветовал, подключить PaperClip для обработки изображений и какой-нибудь гем авторизации, например, Devise.